# query to count the number of values in a columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called application. with this column (app_status), where the it can take only one of these three value 'accepted', 'rejected' or pending. and I want to display the number of each status. In another word I want a query that will give me something like:

```
application_status     :     number_of_status
--------------------------------------------
accepted               |         4
--------------------------------------------
rejected:              |         5
--------------------------------------------
pending:               |         10
```

in Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select count(case when app_status= 'accepted' then 1 else null end) as Accepted, 
count(case when app_status='rejected' then 1 else null end) as Rejected, 
count(case when app_status='pending'then 1 else null end) as Pending
From Application
```

--Jim

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` for this.

```
SELECT app_status, COUNT(app_status) AS NumberOfStatus
FROM application
GROUP BY app_status HAVING (COUNT(app_status)>1)
ORDER BY NumberOfStatus DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler:

```
select application_status, count(application_status) as number_of_status 
from application group by application_status
```